# selecting spring profile maven commands

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat8

Am having spring profiles configured in my application like `DEV`, `TEST`, `QA`. how can i select those profiles using maven commands.

As of now, am selecting those profiles using.

```
clean package -P DEV
```

But also i have other configuration like,

```
clean pacakage -Dtuf.environment="DEV" -Dapi.environment="DEV" -Dspring.profiles.active="DEV"
```

So, in these two commands which one is best to select. Also, if i want to pass these profile as run time argument from tomcat vmarguments how can i pass these as arguments.

Am using tomcat 8.5 version

Comment: Spring profiles are intended for runtime not for build time...why do you need them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use -Dspring.profiles.active without declaring it every time by creating a script `setenv.sh` in the bin folder of tomcat, in which you override the variable JAVA_OPTS